# Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-12436 error while using AVAssetImageGenerator

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avplayer, http-live-streaming

I am using a remote link to play a VOD HLS video using AVPlayer. It's playing fine.
Once the video is playable I am using generateCGImagesAsynchronouslyForTimes to get the thumbnail for a specific time.
But it is responding with following error:-

> Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11800 "The operation could
> not be completed" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=An unknown error
> occurred (-12436), NSLocalizedDescription=The operation could not be
> completed, NSUnderlyingError=0x2805331e0 {Error
> Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-12436 "(null)"}}

It would really help if anybody can help me with the error reason.